# hadoop copy preserving the ownership/permissions

Tags: hadoop

Is there any way to retain the ownership/permissions while copying files in hadoop?
Tried `hadoop fs -cp -p <src> <dest>` . Didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes of course you can.** But I recommend you to use **distcp**, is an advanced tool to copy data between clusters or on the same cluster, you have a lot of option to optimize the execution. This command will run a mapreduce, so for a long copies it will take less time and you will can preserve all attributes.

## Example:

```
hadoop distcp /source_dir/data \
              /target_dir/data

hadoop distcp /source_dir/dataA \
              /source_dir/dataB \
              /target_dir/
```

For all attributes:

- r: replication number
- b: block size
- u: user
- g: group
- p: permission
- c: checksum-type
- a: ACL
- x: XAttr
- t: timestamp

## Another example, but preserving all attributes:

```
hadoop distcp -p rbugpcaxt \
              /source_dir/data \
              /target_dir/data
```

You can read more about this command on [hadoop-distcp](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html)
The most important is not the owner and group or permissions, you can change it easy after copy command, the most important attributes are ACL, block size, replication number, and some times timestamp, this are extra properties that you can not change so easy after a simply copy (hdfs dfs -cp).

Answer (score -1):

There is not, but you can (assuming you have the appropriate permissions) change the ownership after you copy the files.

Answer (score -1):

It is currently not possible to create two copies of the file while copying permissions -- Depending on your use case, however, an option may be to move the files instead. For instance, I have had to change the location of a file and its permissions, and also wanted to keep a backup (permissions didn't matter) so I moved with permissions to the new location and copied back to the original without. I know that's not very helpful, but that's the best we have in Hadoop at the moment.

Comment: Yea, I ended up moving the files.